# html table in webbrowser (VB)

Tags: html, vb.net, browser, html-table

I'm working on creating a table from an access database. It cycles through the database finding any matches and then displays them in a webbrowser.

Currently I have rows showing but I'd love to do an onclick show the rows below. I'm not sure if it's even possible with this type of layout. Thoughts on a different approach?

```
    Private Sub Populate_HtmlTable(ByRef dt As DataTable)


    Dim table As String = "<html>" & vbCrLf & _
        "<head>" & vbCrLf & _
        "</head>" & vbCrLf & _
        "<body > " & vbCrLf & _
        "<table>"


    Label5.Text = "RESULTS RETURNED : " + dt.Rows.Count.ToString
    If dt.Rows.Count = False Then
        table += "<tr><td> No Results Returned</td> </tr>"

    Else
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            table += "<tr>"

            Dim tCellDataItem As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim tCellIntervention As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim tCellTags As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim tCellPR As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim tCellGrade As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim tCellRR As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim tCellEvidence As New HtmlTableCell()
            Dim tCellBibliography As New HtmlTableCell()


            'Cell Intervention Title
            Dim data_item As String = ""
            If Not IsDBNull(dt.Rows(i)("data_item")) Then data_item = "<strong>" + dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString() + "</strong><br>"
            tCellDataItem.InnerHtml = data_item

            'Cell Intervention
            Dim intervention As String = ""
            If Not IsDBNull(dt.Rows(i)("intervention")) Then intervention = dt.Rows(i)(3).ToString()
            tCellIntervention.InnerHtml = intervention

            'Cell Tags
            Dim tags As String = ""
            If Not IsDBNull(dt.Rows(i)("Tags")) Then tags = dt.Rows(i)(10).ToString()
            tCellTags.InnerHtml = tags


            'Add Cells to Rows and then add Rows to table
            table += "<td valign=""top"">" + tCellDataItem.InnerHtml + "</td>"
            'table += "</tr>"

            '1st Drop Down'
            'Interventions


//IF THEY CLICK HERE
    table += "<tr><td style=""border:solid; border-bottom-width:2px;""> Intervention Description</td> </tr>"
//DISPLAY THESE ROWS             
            table += "<tr><td>" + tCellIntervention.InnerHtml + "</td></tr>"
            table += "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
            table += "<tr><td><strong>Tags: </strong>" + tCellTags.InnerHtml + "</td></tr>"
            table += "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"
  //MORE Info cut out similar to above.
       Next
    End If
    table += "</table></body></html>"

    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Application.StartupPath + "\site.html")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\site.html", table, True)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(Application.StartupPath + "\site.html")
```

Comment: you can bind your dataset to a gridview, then use asp:template to dynamically add buttons to each row. Maybe post some of your vb.net code that pulls your data

Comment: They wanted a more flushed out view so that's why i went with the web browser so i could display multiple rows of the data.

Comment: Does that make sense? Sorry I put more code up so you can see what I was doing and where I grabbed the data from!

Comment: Can you use a gridview control on your site (asp gridview)? I ask because that is exactly what you need--you mentioned your solution is vb.net, so I am assumening this is an aspx page